# Bloomberg APIs - historical index members in Python

Tags: python, api, bloomberg, blpapi, pdblp

I'm trying to get index members using Bloomberg APIs in Python. I have no issues getting current constituents, but I want a historical list (*example: what where Russell 1000 or S&P 500 constituents as of Q1 1995*).

To get the current index members I can use following:

In excel I can use INDX_MEMBERS to get the constituents:

```
=BDS("Index Ticker", INDX_MEMBERS)
```

In Python:

```
import pybbg

def Main():
    bbg = pybbg.Pybbg()
    IndexConst = bbg.bds('IndexName', 'INDX_MEMBERS')
```

or:

```
from tia.bbg import LocalTerminal

resp = LocalTerminal.get_reference_data(index_ticker + ' INDEX', 'INDX_MEMBERS')
members = resp.as_frame().iloc[0,0]
```

Question is how can I get historical index members/constituents. For example I would generate quarterly dates and then I want to know list of constituents for each date.

['2020-06-30',
'2020-03-31',
'2019-12-31',
'2019-09-30',
'2019-06-30',
'2019-03-31',
'2018-12-31' ... '1980-06-30',]

I've tried many solutions, including one below where I'm getting an empty frame:

```
from tia.bbg import LocalTerminal

date_start = datetime.date(2010,6,28)
date_end = datetime.date(2020,6,28)

members_russell1000_3 = LocalTerminal.get_historical('RIY Index', 'INDX_MEMBERS',start=date_start, end=date_end,).as_frame()
```

or the solution below, where regardless of date (now or 20 years ago) I'm receiving the same list of constituents:

```
from xbbg import blp

members =  blp.bds('RIY Index', 'INDX_MEMBERS', DVD_Start_Dt=k[1], DVD_End_Dt=k[1])
```

Variable Explanation to above examples:

- 'RIY Index' - Russell 1000 index ticker
- 'INDX_MEMBERS' - Bloomberg field (flds) for list of index constituents

Alternatively I would be happy if I could get historical list of changes to index constituents with dates (I already have current constituents)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `INDX_MWEIGHT_PX` field and the `END_DATE_OVERRIDE` override (date format: yyyymmdd). It is a reference data request, so probably `bds` and not `bdh` in the python library but I've never used it, so not 100% sure and you may need to try a few solutions until you find the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the below works 
`blp.bds('RIY Index', "INDX_MWEIGHT", END_DATE_OVERRIDE="20210101")`
and gives the same results as an excel query 
`=BDS("RIY Index", "INDX_MWEIGHT_HIST", "END_DATE_OVERRIDE",'20210101')` 
Alternatively using "INDX_MWEIGHT_PX" gives the actual weight and current price values also.